# How do I stop partial-refresh from removing paragraph breaks in the Wordpress Customizer live preview?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added my own settings to the Wordpress customizer and set it up so that it live previews using the "postMessage" method. It is working almost perfectly apart from when I edit a field linked to paragraph text, the preview doesn't show line breaks in the paragraphs. However this is temporary, once the customizer is closed or the page is refreshed the paragraph gaps come back.

I am defining the Customizer sections in the customizer.php using the following code:

```
// About Section Text
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'about__text' , array(
    'default'   => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, odit unde magnam dolores quasi voluptas, impedit a nam inventore atque eaque nobis possimus officiis deleniti quisquam animi deserunt ad ipsa sapiente illo?',
    'transport' => 'postMessage',
) );

// About Section Text (CONTROL)
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'about__text', array(
    'label'      => __( 'About Section Content:', 'mytheme' ),
    'section'    => 'edit__homepage--section',
    'settings'   => 'about__text',
    'priority'   => 3,
    'type'       => 'textarea'
) ) );
```

I am displaying the above theme mod in my index.php file using the following code:

```
    <div class="about__text">
      <?php echo wpautop(get_theme_mod('about__text')); ?>
    </div>
```

Here's my jquery:

```
( function( $ ) {
    wp.customize( 'about__text', function( value ) {
        value.bind( function( newVal ) {
            $( '.about__text' ).html( newVal );
        } );
    } );
} )( jQuery );
```

I've tried experimenting with different jquery objects such as text() and contents() but these either have the same issue or don't work at all.

Doe anyone know if there's a way I can get the javascript preview to honour the paragraph styles? Maybe like a javascript version of wpautop()  ?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are not using Selective Refresh? https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/02/16/selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/

Comment: @Nilambar Many thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it. Please excuse my ignorance though, but there doesn't seem to be anything in the link that fixes my issue. The example code not only causes the theme_mod to still lose the p breaks still, but also cause the preview to reload the entire preview, which I was trying to avoid. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selective refresh like this. Values are rendered server side so no need to extra JS. And since only selected wrapper element is refresh, it is more efficient than full page reload in Customizer. In the following example content only in `.about__text` is refreshed. Since rendering is done server side, no need to look for JS alternative of wpautop function. I believe this would be one alternative for your problem mentioned in the question.

```
function wpso_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial(
        'about__text',
        array(
            'selector'        => '.about__text',
            'render_callback' => function(){
                echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( get_theme_mod('about__text') ) );
            },
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpso_customize_register' );
```

Comment: Fantastic, this works perfectly. It also adds the the visual edit icon which is a great bonus